# How to set Rails dev server to webbrick instead of Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, puma

I'm using Puma on Heroku for my server.  When i have the Puma gem installed my dev environment boots up with Puma as the server.  I don't seem to be able to shut that off without pulling the pum gem from my gemfile.

I like the idea of using the save server in development as production but the puma server make it difficult to track my debug statements.  Also  i don't seem to have a way to change max threads, comes up as 16 in dev even though my puma.rb file sets it to 1.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just use puma in production mode. In your gemfile change `gem 'puma'` with

```
#Gemfile
group :production do
  gem 'puma'
end
```

and then run `bundle install --without production` to install the gem .

Comment: To add comment, Rails' default is to use Webrick - so if you don't include any external servers in the dependencies, you'll be okay

Comment: I think i never did a bundle install after moving the gem to Group :production, just updates.  doing the above worked and it's behaving as expectd

Comment: `bundle install --without production` works for me. Thanks.