# Change local web server back to WEBrick in Rails from Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick, puma

I was following the Heroku docs on getting Puma set up and entered this command:

```
bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}
```

Which made it so that now I run puma in my development environment whenever I run a `rails s`. But or whatever reason Puma is causing havok. How do I switch back to using WEBrick??

Tried

```
bundle exec webrick -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}
```

But of course, command is not found: webrick. Knew that' be too easy...

Thanks!

Comment: What does your Procfile say?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To run the local server in development with webrick you should only have to specify it when running `rails server`:

```
rails server webrick
```

You may get it to default back to webrick again if you move puma to the production group of your Gemfile:

```
group :production do
  gem 'puma'
end
```

Then bundle without the production group:

```
bundle install --without production
```

Comment: The first part works, but putting "gem 'puma'" within the production group does not do it.

Comment: confirming the behavior posted by JosephK  on rails 4.2.5

Comment: That's because putting it in the `:production` group doesn't automatically stop it from being installed on `:development`. You need to tell it explicitly to not install it with `bundle install --without production`

Answer (score 3):

Per the following:

[How to set Rails dev server to webbrick instead of Puma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125369/how-to-set-rails-dev-server-to-webbrick-instead-of-puma)

You want to change your Gemfile to:

```
group :production do
  gem 'puma'
end
```

And running `bundle install --without production` will set WEBrick as the non-production (development & test) server and Puma to production.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the puma gem from the gemfile and bundle it.

and start the application. you can see the webrick app server start info in the console.

Default app web server is Webrick

Comment: Yep. Works a treat. Puma after 5.0.2 caused some major slowdowns for us - unusable. See https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/2484. It never got fixed and now there are security issues unless you upgrade. Moving back over to Webrick since it's the default for dev anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Run with:

```
bundle exec rails server -u webrick -p 3000 -e staging
```

Also you may need to have `webrick` installed. But as I remember it is a part of standard library

```
bundle add webrick
```